# Cannot connect to hive using hive-jdbc in OpenText

Tags: jdbc, hive, birt, bigdata

[image: Hive Connection]

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hive.service.auth.HiveAuthFactory
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createBinaryTransport(HiveConnection.java:478)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:201)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:176)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager$WrappedDriver.connect(JDBCDriverManager.java:1274)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at com.actuate.data.oda.jdbc.drivers.AcDriverConnectionFactory.getConnection(AcDriverConnectionFactory.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.doConnect(JDBCDriverManager.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.tryCreateConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.testConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.util.DriverLoader.testConnection(DriverLoader.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.util.DriverLoader.testConnection(DriverLoader.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.hive.ui.profile.HiveSelectionPageHelper.testConnection(HiveSelectionPageHelper.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.hive.ui.profile.HiveSelectionPageHelper.access$4(HiveSelectionPageHelper.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.hive.ui.profile.HiveSelectionPageHelper$2.widgetSelected(HiveSelectionPageHelper.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.actions.NewDataSourceAction.run(NewDataSourceAction.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your question is unlikely to receive a good answer in its current form, as absolutely no details about our configuration or environment are provided. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for ideas on how to improve. Good luck, and happy hacking!

Comment: Kindly add more details on what code was written , when this issue is seen.